# How to delete data from database inline using Symfony

Tags: html, symfony

I'm new with Symfony and I'm trying to delete some data from the database using an html table, something that looks like this but I don't know where to start:

[image: layout]

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Start here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html

Comment: thank you for your response .I already now the basics of how to add,edit or delete data from the database usong doctrine but what i want is to click a delete button in an html table to delete the clicked row

Comment: Please show what code `you have already created`...

Comment: "i want is to click a delete button in an html table to delete the clicked row". Did you actually just want to update your view ?

Comment: I have no code yet just doing some research

Answer (score 0):

There are basically 3 choices, whether using symphony or not:

1. A link to a page (look at Symfony "routes") including the information which entry to delete.

   A nice trick is to use the same page and add a query parameter.
   This would look something like this in twig:

   ```
   {% for row in table %}
      <a href="?delete={{row.id}}">delete</a>
   {% endfor %}
   ```

   And in symfony:

   ```
   if($request->get->has('delete'))
   {
       //delete it from the database
   }
   //the code that displays your table
   ```

   This is the easiest way but has a few disadvantages. It is slow as the whole page has to be loaded again. The browsers back-button might not behave as the user might expect.
2. A html form doing basically the same as 1. but with post

   ```
   {% for row in table %}
     <form action="" method="POST">
       <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="{{row.id}}">
       <input type="submit" value="delete">
     </form>
   {% endfor %}
   ```

   And in symfony use `$request->request`
3. Ajax triggered by an onclick event

   A javascript deleterow function would send the id via ajax to a special symphony route that returns an JSONResponse and when successful delete the DOM Element with the row.

   This is much more complicated and would need a lot more research on your part, but it is the modern way.

Comment: thank you for the answer and the time u took to post this i will try it